# Was default_marker removed from mapbox-gl.js

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to use the `default_marker` and/or `secondary_marker` in mapbox-gl.js however it appears they have been removed from the sprite.json in streets-v9 (probably v8 too). I've found a working example in streets-v7 where they were part of the sprite.json/sprit.png, but they are gone now.

How can I get these back or what is the new replacement? I've gone through the new sprint.png but I don't see anything similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apologies for the change, ongle! We've recently worked to [standardize the icons](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-styles/issues/241) [available across all the Mapbox styles](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-styles#standard-icons) which, unfortunately, required some breaking changes.

The closest replacement to `default_marker` is `marker-15`. The appearance of this marker will be different per style.

You may also choose to [upload your own marker image per this guide](https://www.mapbox.com/help/custom-markers/).

Comment: Yes, I ended up adding my own marker. That marker-15 is really just a dot and doesn't stand out very well. Strange that there is no decent default marker or map pin, such a common metaphor.